# How to preset some value in search box of windows 7's open file dialog

Tags: .net, winforms

In windows 7's open file dialog, at the upper right corner there is a search box. How can I set some value automatically after the dialog is opened?

Comment: very interesting question, can I ask why you want to control this with the search box instead of using the Filter by extension? What is your real use case? I could not find anything about this, not sure MS exposes any APIs, eventually there is something in the Windows 7 SDK but not wrapped yet in .NET Framework.

Comment: A use case would make this question easier to answer.

Comment: I have an app which user normally do some search and has input something in some other UI. Then the users need to load a file among a large amount other files. The file name (not in extension) contains a string the user has already input. This is just a user friendly feature.